# Why wont a map inside of a struct accept an assignment

Tags: csv, go, struct

```
type DateData struct {
    Count     int
    Districts map[string]int
}
```

This is the struct that I am having issues with.

```
var dates = make(map[string]DateData)
```

and this is how I am initialing and using said struct

Why do I get an error of  `panic: assignment to entry in nil map`

when I try to assigning a value to the districts map like so: dates["1/1/06"].Districts["1"] = 1
I am not able to assign a value to the Districts field

Here is the full code for context :

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

type Report struct {
    Date      string `json:"date"`
    Address   string `json:"address"`
    District  string `json:"district"`
    Beat      string `json:"beat"`
    Grid      string `json:"grid"`
    Crimedesc string `json:"crimedesc"`
    UCRCode   string `json:"ucr_ncic_code"`
    Lat       string `json:"latitude"`
    Lon       string `json:"longitude"`
}

type DateData struct {
    Count     int
    Districts map[string]int
}

func main() {

    reports := CreateReport()

    var dates = make(map[string]DateData)

    for _, report := range reports {

        dateIndex := strings.LastIndex(report.Date, "/")
        date := report.Date[0 : dateIndex+3]

        val, ok := dates[date]
        if !ok {
            dates[date] = DateData{
                Count: 1,
            }

        } else {
            val.Count += 1
            dates[date] = val
        }

    }

    dates["1/1/06"].Districts["1"] = 1

    fmt.Println("dates slice", dates)
    // fmt.Println("dates slice", dates)

}

func CreateReport() []Report {
    // csvFile, err := os.Open("./files/sacramento-jan-2006.csv")
    csvFile, err := os.Open("./files/sacramento-test.csv")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("error opeining file", err)
    }

    defer csvFile.Close()

    reader := csv.NewReader(csvFile)
    var reports []Report

    for {
        line, err := reader.Read()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        } else if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("error reading file", err)
        }

        reports = append(reports, Report{
            Date:      line[0],
            Address:   line[1],
            District:  line[2],
            Beat:      line[3],
            Grid:      line[4],
            Crimedesc: line[5],
            UCRCode:   line[6],
            Lat:       line[7],
            Lon:       line[8],
        })

    }

    return reports
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is complaining about the `Districts` map, because that map is nil. Initialize it as:

```
        if !ok {
            dates[date] = DateData{
                Count: 1,
                Districts: make(map[string]int),
            }
```